# Code keeps resetting every time I make a commit in intellij

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Intellij is acting funny.
https://github.com/TeamTrillium/Trillium/blob/master/src/main/java/net/gettrillium/trillium/api/Configuration.java#L64

If you look at that class (specifically lines 67-68) you will notice that

`private static String PREFIX = "broadcast.";`

and

`public static String PRE_NORMAL = PREFIX + "regular-broadcasts.";`

should actually be on lines 64-65.

See, the problem is that whenever I place those lines on lines 64-65 (as they should be so they wont error) and make a commit in intellij (through the button), those lines of code specifically alone in the entire project without anything else REVERT back to lines 67-68 and re-error!

If you look at the commits on that project, you'll see that I spammed a little trying to fix the problem to no avail.

Oh and here's the thing, I had to buy a new harddisk so I reinstalled intellij on this new one and the problem PERSISTED! Those lines of code are cursed.

I tried editing those lines of code online from github and pulled from intellij. It fixed the problem but after committing... It resets.

Does anyone know why these specific lines of code keep resetting? Any if so, do you know how to fix this VERY VERY irritating problem?